# Validar si no existe un valor en mongo db

Tags: json, mongodb, jsonobject, jsonarray, mongoatlas

lo que pasa es que necesito validar que no exista un campo dentro de un objeto para así agregarlo en caso de que no exista.

es decir:

```
{
    "nombre": "Pavlov",
    "primer_apellido": "Gatecliffe",
}

{
    "nombre": "Stoddard",
    "primer_apellido": "Tullot",
    "segundo_apellido": "Harrald",
}
```

de esos dos objetos necesito vaidar que hay alguno que no tiene un campo (en este caso segundo apellido) y si no lo tiene agregarselo, cómo podría hacer el script en la consola de mongo para hacer esa validación?

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad ¿podrías mostrar que has intentado con código y poner la etiqueta del lenguaje que usas?

Comment: En caso de que no exista, ¿qué valor le vas a asignar al nuevo campo? Supongamos que tienes más de un documento en la colección a los que les haga falta dicho campo, ¿le asignarás a todos el mismo valor?